# Increase Criteria in a WHERE Clause

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Sub UpdateX() 
 
    Dim dbs As Database  
 
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("SOShops.mdb") 
     
    dbs.Execute "UPDATE Employees " _ 
        & "SET Payrate = 12 " _ 
        & "WHERE DaysAtWork = " & Me.txtDaysWorked & _
        & "AND HoursePerDay = " & Me.txtHrsWorked & "" 
         
    dbs.Close 
 
End Sub
```

I tried the above and received a

> Run-Time Error 3075 or a syntax error stating "Missing Operator in
> Query Expression.

Comment: You at least need a space before the `AND` - `" AND HoursePerDay` so it doesn't run together with the end of `Me.txtDaysWorked` - With something like this, it's better to create the string in a variable that you can see the result of before you try to execute it. If you had done that, it probably would have been obvious.

Comment: It looks like you try to put a space at the end of each line to accomplish this, but with it organized like this, it would make more sense to put the space on the beginning of each part of the string so you can easily see if you are not missing one.

Comment: Appreciate your advice. Things are working good for me now

Answer (score 2):

Already discussed in the comments: The way you concatenate the pieces of your SQL statement will glue the content of variable of `Me.txtDaysWorked` and the next piece of the SQL statement `AND HoursePerDay` together, resulting in something like `50AND HoursePerDay` which will invalid the SQL statement.

Now when it comes to create SQL statements in VBA, it is easy to put some kind of syntax error in it. Like braX said in the comments, it is a big help if you write the statement into an intermediate variable. If something fails, you can easily check the statement with the debugger.

Also, indent your SQL statement and add Linebreaks, this helps to read the statement. The database engine doesn't care about them.

I know indentation of SQL statements is a matter of taste (or style guides), but I usually stick to the following. It makes the statement easier to read and ensures that you always have at least one space between the single parts (even if you don't put a newline at the end).

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "UPDATE Employees" & vbCrLf _ 
    & "   SET Payrate = 12" & vbCrLf _ 
    & " WHERE DaysAtWork = " & Me.txtDaysWorked & vbCrLf _
    & "   AND HoursePerDay = " & Me.txtHrsWorked 
Debug.Print sql  ' <-- for testing purposes, can be removed or commented out.
dbs.Execute sql
```

And be careful when you put content of variables into the statement. `Me.txtDaysWorked` sounds like an textbox on a user form. You need to ensure that it contains a numeric value, else your SQL statement will fail.

Comment: Very much appreciate it. Its just working fine for me now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
    dbs.Execute "UPDATE Employees " & _ 
        "SET Payrate = 12 " & _ 
        "WHERE DaysAtWork = " & Me.txtDaysWorked & " " & _
        "AND HoursePerDay = " & Me.txtHrsWorked & ""
```